# Efficient means of null terminating an unsigned char buffer in a string append function?

Tags: c++, c, buffer, arrays, null-terminated

I've been writing a "Byte Buffer" utility module - just a set of functions for personal use in low level development.

Unfortunately, my `ByteBuffer_Append(...)` function doesn't work properly when it null terminates the character at the end, and/or adds extra room for the null termination character. One result, when this is attempted, is when I call `printf()` on the buffer's data (a cast to `(char*)` is performed): I'll get only a section of the string, as the first null termination character within the buffer will be found.

So, what I'm looking for is a means to incorporate some kind of null terminating functionality within the function, but I'm kind of drawing a blank in terms of what would be a good way of going about this, and could use a point in the right direction.

Here's the code, if that helps:

```
void ByteBuffer_Append( ByteBuffer_t* destBuffer, uInt8* source, uInt32 sourceLength )
{
    if ( !destBuffer )
    {
        puts( "[ByteBuffer_Append]: param 'destBuffer' received is NULL, bailing out...\n" );

        return;
    }

    if ( !source )
    {
        puts( "[ByteBuffer_Append]: param 'source' received is NULL, bailing out...\n" );

        return;
    }

    size_t byteLength = sizeof( uInt8 ) * sourceLength;

    // check to see if we need to reallocate the buffer

    if ( destBuffer->capacity < byteLength || destBuffer->length >= sourceLength )
    {
        destBuffer->capacity += byteLength;

        uInt8* newBuf = ( uInt8* ) realloc( destBuffer->data, destBuffer->capacity );

        if ( !newBuf )
        {
            Mem_BadAlloc( "ByteBuffer_Append - realloc" );
        }

        destBuffer->data = newBuf;
    }

    uInt32 end = destBuffer->length + sourceLength;

    // use a separate pointer for the source data as
    // we copy it into the destination buffer

    uInt8* pSource = source;

    for ( uInt32 iBuffer = destBuffer->length; iBuffer < end; ++iBuffer )
    {
        destBuffer->data[ iBuffer ] = *pSource;

        ++pSource;
    }

    // the commented code below
    // is where the null termination
    // was happening

    destBuffer->length += sourceLength; // + 1;

    //destBuffer->data[ destBuffer->length - 1 ] = '\0';
}
```

Many thanks to anyone providing input on this.

Comment: So your commented out code is not adding the null terminator in the right place or? What is the problem with that line?

Comment: This check is not OK: `if ( destBuffer->capacity < byteLength || destBuffer->length >= sourceLength )`; should be length+byteLength>=capacity

Comment: You can't have a byte buffer *and* null termination, unless your buffer is not supposed to hold any zeros.

Comment: When null terminating `n` bytes pointed by `p`, code should be `p[n]=0`; also you do not count the 0 terminating byte in realloc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your issue is caused by memory corruption.

You have to fix the following three problems:

1 check if allocated space is enough

```
if ( destBuffer->capacity < byteLength || destBuffer->length >= sourceLength )
```

does not properly check if buffer reallocation is needed,
replace with

```
if ( destBuffer->capacity <= destBuffer->length+byteLength )
```

2 allocating enough space

```
destBuffer->capacity += byteLength;
```

is better to become

```
destBuffer->capacity = destBuffer->length + byteLength + 1;
```

3 properly null terminating

```
destBuffer->data[ destBuffer->length - 1 ] = '\0';
```

should become

```
destBuffer->data[ destBuffer->length ] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++, a list of `char`s terminating by a `'\0'` is a string. There are a set of string functions, such as `strcpy()`, `strcmp()`, they take `char *` as parameter, and when they find a `'\0'`, they the string end there. In your case, `printf("%s", buf)` treats buf as a string, so when it find a `'\0'`, it stops print.

If you are doing a buffer, that means any data include `'\0'` is normal data in the buffer. So you should avoid to use string functions. To print a buffer, you need to implement your own function.

Comment: Would you recommend I come up with my own delimiter of some sort, then?